# How to properly mock a private ExecutorService's submit method in JMockit

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, jmockit

I have a class which contains a private ExecutorService instance. Within the class I have a method which runs the submit method and catches the RejectedExecutionException. However I am having trouble in mocking the ExecutorService instance to throw the exception so that I can complete my test coverage. I am using JMockit 1.45.

I have already gone through the JMockit tutorial and other sites; whether i use @Mocked, @Capturing, or even create a new fake class it doesn't seem to work.

```
// Implemented Class:
public class TaskRegister {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public TaskRegister() {
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public void executeTask(Runnable task) {
        try {
            this.executor.submit(task);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage);
        }
    }
}


// Unit Test Class:
public class TestTaskRegister {
    @Tested
    private TaskRegister tested;

    private static int counter;

    @Test // this works
    public void runNormalTask() throws InterruptedException {
        counter = 0;
        Runnable mockTask = new Runnable() {
            counter++;
        }

        tested.executeTask(mockTask);
        Thread.sleep(100); // Allow executor to finish other thread.
        assertEquals(1, counter);
    }

    @Test // this doesn't work, will have missing invocation error.
    public void throwsError (@Capturing ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
        counter = 0;

        // somehow the tested class still runs the actual executor 
        // and not the mocked one.
        new Expectations() {{
             executor.submit((Runnable) any);
             result = new RejectedExecutionException();
        }};

        Runnable mockTask = new Runnable() {
            // some task
        }

        tested.executeTask(mockTask);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        assertEquals(0, counter);
    }
}
```

I expect the @Capturing to intercept the real executor implementation and throw the exception upon executor.submit being called, but it isn't doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking by `@Capturing` is potentially expensive and can cause unexpected results in certain cases, so (currently) all `java.*` classes are excluded. So, `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` doesn't get mocked in this test (it can be with `@Mocked`).

In practice, the `RejectedExecutionException` exception will never occur (not with a `ThreadPoolExecutor` at least - probably only with a `ForkJoinPool`). So, this test is not worth the effort. In fact, since that exception is a `RuntimeException` you can simply remove the `catch` block entirely.

This is one of the bad things that happen with the (ab)use of mocking libraries: people sometimes use them to test impossible situations, and therefore write useless tests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However I have tried using @Mocked and new Expectations but the test will always return a missing invocation error. May I also ask if I remove the catch block what is the best way to log the exception then?

Comment: It should work with a `@Mocked ThreadPoolExecutor executor` parameter in the test method. That runtime exception should be logged as any other, that is, at a central place and at a higher level in the call stack of the application, where all unhandled exceptions get caught and then written to a log file. That's what's normally done in the real apps I've seen. Low-level code should allow such exceptions to be propagated to the caller, unless they really have a way of handling them.

Comment: I have managed to succeed with mocking of executor using ThreadPoolExecutor and will be selecting this answer as the best fit. Plus I am also more inline with the view that my current class is already a base class and does not need additional injections / configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. In JMockit 1.48 the `@Capturing` restriction on `java.*` classes was relaxed to allow `java.util.concurrent`, so `@Capturing ExecutorService` now mocks the implementation classes (like `ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new constructor with the `Executor` in parameters.
Hence your class will be more configurable (because currently you can only use one kind of executor) and you'll be able test the class by manually instantiate it with a mocked executor.

```
public class TaskRegister {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public TaskRegister(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public TaskRegister() {
        this(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
    }

    public void executeTask(Runnable task) {
        try {
            this.executor.submit(task);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is already able to be tested as is. Personally, I don't know if such a class has a good reason to even exist, but exposing an implementation detail (the use of an `ExecutorService`) may not be desirable. Also IMO, constructor injection is a bad choice in general - I prefer injection into annotated fields when using DI.

Comment: Well it's not really an implementation detail since there are several types of executor with a configurable number of threads. Forcing the users to have only one configuration available isn't a great design imo.

Comment: It is an implementatoin detail of the `TaskRegister` class, as it simply allows for tasks to be executed in background threads. This class is a higher level abstraction, and the threading/concurrency API it uses is an encapsulated implementation detail. So, I think you are confused about what class or API design even is supposed to be.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Parking aside the correctness of DI, I have also tried using "@Autowired" to inject the executor. While this can certainly remove the problem of mocking the executor, the problem I now face is how to use the real implementation if I want to test correct execution. JMockit's "@Injectable" will mock the executor for all test cases. One way of correcting this is to actually use a real executor as the mock but then I wouldn't really be testing the actual underlying implmentation...

Comment: @FuJie You can instantiate a specific instance for `throwsError`, where you configure the mock to throw an exception. For the other tests, simply use a normal executor service, like the one in the default constructor